# bash: bad substitution with function parameter

Tags: bash, macos

when Removing part of a string , the code is OK

```
var="1125X549+0+192"

echo "${var%X*}"
```

When handled in terminal with function:

```
converto3(){

  echo "$2"

  A="${$2%X*}"
  # echo $A
  # convert $1 -crop $2 "three.png"
}

converto3 Group\ 7@3x\(1\).png  1125X549+0+192
```

It reports ,

> converto3:4: bad substitution

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
a="${2%X*}"
echo "$a"
```

Remember that you're using `"${var%X*}"` in your shell not `"${$var%X*}"`

If you check `man bash` it shows following syntax for removing a matching  suffix pattern.

```
${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}
```